# Унаследовать форму

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу создать форму на основе существующей. Пытаюсь унаследовать базовую форму-родителя: `public partial class Order : EmployeeClass.DlgActionBase`. Но пишет ошибку в дизайнере

> Could not load file or assembly 'Orders, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. Не удается найти указанный файл.

как решить проблему? я так понимаю, что, на данном этапе, на месте моей формы должна была полностью отобразиться родительская?

Comment: Проверьте, что прилинкованы все необходимые проекты. Проверьте, что без ошибок собирается проект, в котором описана форма, от которой вы хотите наследоваться, если он включен в то же решение.